# how to check the message published from redis sentinel to redis master?

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

Question Background:

I deploy a redis cluster in k8s cluster and use Redis-Sentinel to implement ha for redis cluster. My redis cluster structure likes below:

One master

One slave

three sentinel （serve a specific redis cluster)

When i login the container of the one of sentinels, i execute a command:

sentinel sentinels mymaster

Luckly, i get a desirable output. These are two sentinel's infos. After a period of time, i execute "sentinels mymaster" command again, i found that there is a additional sentinel and don't find this instance through IP address or runId。

I know that sentinel discover other sentinels and master and slave through sub the channel of **sentinel**:hello in redis master.

Question:

how to check the message published from redis sentinel to redis master? I have opened log for master and set the log level to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the Sentinel's activity (when it discovers a sentinel, a replica, failsover to a new master, etc.) in the sentinel log file, not the master. If a sentinel is running on a host, it will be in the same directory the master or replica log file is. For me on CentOS it's `/var/log/redis/sentinel.log`.